# Javascript AND (&&) operator is not working inside if block

Tags: javascript, and-operator

I have a JavaScript login validation block, however my `if` block is partially working, i.e condition after the AND(&&) is not being checked resulting not applying validation on password, here is my code snippet.

```js
function validateLogin(){
    var userid = document.getElementById('user_id');
    var passid = document.getElementById('pass_id');

    if((userid.value.length < 3) && (passid.value.length < 6)) {
        document.getElementById('user_error').setAttribute("style","color:red")
        document.getElementById('user_error').innerHTML="invalid username/password.";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="login_form" name="login" onsubmit=" return validateLogin()" >
<div>
     <input class="user_login_form" id='user_id' type="text"  required tabindex="1"  name="user_id" autofocus autocomplete=off  placeholder ="User Name">
</div>
<div>
    <input class="user_login_form" id='pass_id' required type="password" tabindex="2"  name="user_pass" placeholder ="Password">
    <p id ="user_error"></p>
</div>
<input class="user_login_submit" type="submit" id='btnLogin' tabindex="3" name="login_btnSubmit" value="LOGIN" >
```

Comment: `userid.value.length >3`

Comment: Say your condition aloud, and compare it to what you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's optimization of `if`. If first part is false, then further comparisons are not executed because of `false && Anything` results in `false`

You need to compare using `OR`

```js
function validateLogin() {
  var userid = document.getElementById('user_id');
  var passid = document.getElementById('pass_id');
  if ((userid.value.length < 3) || (passid.value.length < 6)) {
    document.getElementById('user_error').setAttribute("style", "color:red")
    document.getElementById('user_error').innerHTML = "invalid username/password.";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="login_form" name="login" onsubmit=" return validateLogin()">
  <div>
    <input class="user_login_form" id='user_id' type="text" required tabindex="1" name="user_id" autofocus autocomplete=off placeholder="User Name">

  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="user_login_form" id='pass_id' required type="password" tabindex="2" name="user_pass" placeholder="Password">
    <p id="user_error"></p>
  </div>
  <input class="user_login_submit" type="submit" id='btnLogin' tabindex="3" name="login_btnSubmit" value="LOGIN">
```

Comment: Its not working even when my user_id condition is set to true, ie user_id is greater than 3, still it doesn't check for pass_id

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi it's absolutely working in the snippet above, you confused AND and OR.

Comment: your code is working, I'm asking above when AND is used.

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi When using AND your both conditions must be true (means email and pass must be invalid at same time). If one of them is not true (e.g. email is correct, but password is not) then you do not go inside "if". For OR: either email or password must be too short in order to execute "if"

Answer (score 0):

You want to use OR here. So your throw your error if userid length is less than 3 OR passid length is less than 6.

`if((userid.value.length < 3) || (passid.value.length < 6))`